# Django view - redirect to one page and open another in new tab

Tags: python, django

I have a Django view that looks like this:

```
def edit_view(request, pk)

    # do something ...

    messages.success(request, "Success!")
    return redirect('index')
```

The view should redirect to "index" (like in the code above), but it should also, at the same time, open another (second) page in new tab.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I think this task is not for Django but javascript. For the Django view could be posible to send a JsonResponse containing the redirect link and the new tab one.

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "redirect": "/some/redirect/link",
    "new_tab": "/some/new-tab/link"
  }
}
```

Then use JS

```
window.open(response.data.new_tab)
window.location.href = response.data.redirect
```

### Expanded Example

I'm assuming you are using a post request, so in your view

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.urls import reverse

def edit_view(request, pk)
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do something ...
        return JsonResponse({
            "status": "ok",
            "data": {
                "redirect": reverse('app:some_view'),
                "new_tab": reverse('app:some_other_view')
            }
        })
```

In your template, the post must be using promises through the `Fetch API`

```
<script>
  def aysncPost(url) {
    fetch(url, {method: 'post'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      ...
      window.open(data.new_tab);
      window.location.href = data.redirect;
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here you have some useful docs

- [Django JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: I prefer `window.open(URL, '_blank');`, but this is how I'd do it. Odd use-case @OP has tho

Comment: I'm using built in Django templating engine, can you expand the example a bit? I'm not sure how to redirect to a page and send json data (response) along with redirect. Also, how do I access that data with JS in my template? Where will it be stored?

Comment: The Django view will not redirect, it will return json data.
The json data is not stored just consumed, think about it as if you make a request to a REST API.